# Rich text: VARCHAR, TEXT or BLOB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes, varchar

**Question:** In my web application (php/MySQL) I will be saving rich text. This may be anything from a couple words to several pages length essay. I’m sure I could get away with using `VARCHAR`, `TEXT` or `BLOB` to store markdown or HTML from a rich text editor like TinyMCE. Which should I use?

**My findings so far:** In all my searching this week I’ve not found anything that tried to be a definitive source as to which would be best in general. I think `VARCHAR` is a standard and `TEXT` is not. `BLOB` is for binary data and so is overkill. `TEXT` may be deprecated in some DBMS. One major concern I have revolves around my ignorance as to how `VARCHAR` is saved to the database. I.e., if I max it out (or leave it undefined) will it waste storage or memory if there is only a few words in it? Or as a modern DB does MySQL not store blank data as reserved space? My research has indicated that the performance difference is very minor in modern systems between `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` queries. Also, I do not need to do many text searches in the content. I’m not planning on any, however, the ability to do so would be a benefit, long term.

**Tentative Conclusion:** I think to be best and standards compliant (low priority) I should make a `VARCHAR` type with no limit. Then just insert the markdown, HTML or textile data in there. I assume not specifying a limit would max out the data capacity on the server.

**Would** `VARCHAR` **be the best standard to employ? Or have I gone completely off the rails in my research?**

Comment: You will be appalled at how inconsistent databases are when it comes to standards.  Compliance should be _really_ low priority.

Comment: If you don't know how big things might get, use `MEDIUMTEXT` (16M limit) for data in a known character encoding (such as utf8) or `MEDIUMBLOB` (16M) for non-text (eg images).  Html qualifies as text.

Comment: Thanks Rick James. I think `MEDIUMTEXT` will fit my needs. I should add that I confirmed that TEXT is stored off table via pointers, in case future readers wonder.

Comment: I think [this answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023513/3626537) addresses some of your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the size of the data you want to save in that field. You should know that there is a limit for `VARCHAR`, and that limit is in bytes, so number of characters that can be stored will depend on the character set you use. For example, if you use `UTF 8`, you will be able to store less amount of data.

To sum it up, there is no "best" solution, but if your data fits in `VARCHAR`, then use it :). If not, you will have to use `TEXT` or `BLOB`, or you will have to zip the data before saving it (Check [compress](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress))